# If a die is thrown $5$ times, what is the probability of throwing at least $3$ ones continuously?

Tags: probability

The Question is:

> Throw a die $5$ times, what is the probability of throwing at least $3$ ones continuously.

I wanted to verify my solution in which I let X denote the positions which the ones could be to count the number of total cases in which there was at least $3$ consecutive items.

Three in a row:

XXX_ _

_ _ XXX

_ XXX _

Four in a row:

_ XXXX

XXXX _

Five in a row:

XXXXX

With this, I assumed that the total number of possible outcomes would be $6$ and the total sample space would be $6^5$ giving us a probability of $1/6^4$.

Additionally, if the question just asked for at least three of any number would that be $36/6^5$ as there are $6$ numbers and $6$ ways each can satisfy the criteria?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're throwing dice, why is the title "Coin flipping (...)" ? Anyway, I would approach this question by reformulating it as: "A die is thrown five times. What is the probability that there are at least three 1's, and that the three are consecutive throws?"

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: Finding the probability that there are three ones can be solved through binomial distributions as 5choose3* (1/6)^5 but I'm not sure how to go about the second constraint.

Comment: There are more than 6 favourable outcomes, because e.g. 11123 and 11161 are different outcomes.

Comment: So I would calculate the product
$$
P(\text{at least three 1's}) \cdot P(\text{three consecutive 1's}~|~\text{at least three 1's})
$$
The first one is easy, it's just
$$
\sum_{k=3}^5 { 5\choose{k}} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^k \left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{5-k} 
$$

Comment: So I do understand how to find the P(at least three 1's) but the former is a bit more hazy for me.

Comment: The approach suggested by @MattiP. is not very efficient: calculating the conditional probability $P(\text{three consecutive 1's}~|~\text{at least three 1's})$ would not be easier at all. Instead, you should finish calculating the number of outcomes. You just need to add the number of outcomes in the six cases you identified. E.g., for XXX--, there are 30 outcomes: the fourth digit is anything but 1, the fifth is arbitrary.

Comment: How are there 30 outcomes for the XXX-- case? I thought it would be XXX-- (5 options)*(5 options) which would give me 25 for the XXX-- case; and then I would multiply this by 3 as there are 3 configurations of 3 consecutive and then a similar argument for four in a row with XXXX- so 5 options for the last and multiply this by two.

Comment: When you get 25 options, you’re discounting the fact that there can be a $1$ as the last digit you roll. So the options become $1*1*1*5*6=30$, because you can roll ANYTHING as the last number.

Comment: In cases like these it might be easier to seperate it by # of 1's rolled, rather than # of 1's in a row, to make sure you are nt double counting and so you can either use 1/6 or 5/6 definitively

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. So correct me if I'm wrong but the total would be 90+10+1/6^5 for the first question?

Comment: @user690808 except for the third "pattern" with 3-in-a-row neither box can be a 1 so the total number for that is 25

Comment: Oh good catch thank you! And if I wanted to find the case of any number being consecutive would I just multiply the total of successful outcomes found by 6?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It must be $\frac{85+10+1}{6^5}$. Possibility N111N only provides $5\times5$ outcomes. 111NN and NN111 both provide $5\times 6$ outcomes.

Comment: @drhab I had worked out that the probability was $\frac{85 + 10 + 1}{6^5}$ while I was away from the computer, which is how I knew your calculation was correct.  I clearly was not paying enough attention to the details when I saw a similar calculation in the comments.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Very recognizable :-).

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ denote not getting a 1. Let $X$ denote getting a 1. Being careful to avoid double counting.

$N(XXXY\_ )=N(\_YXXX)=5*6$

$N(YXXXY)=5*5$

$N(YXXXX)=N(XXXXY)=5$

$N(XXXXX)=1$

Which gives a total of 96 agreeing with drhab's answer. And so the probability is $\frac{96}{6^5}$. If you want the probability of getting at least three consecutive numbers. Then it would be this probability multiplied by 6. Because getting a number say x, at least 3 times, precludes getting any other number y at least 3 times. And the events are disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well then the dice are thrown one by one.

Give the dice chronological numbers $1,2,3,4,5$.

- Let $E$ denote the event that the dice with numbers $1,2,3$ show face 1.
- Let $F$ denote the event that the dice with numbers $2,3,4$ show face 1.
- Let $G$ denote the event that the dice with numbers $3,4,5$ show face 1.

Then to be found is $P(E\cup F\cup G)$ and applying the principle of inclusion/exclusion we find:$$P\left(E\cup F\cup G\right)=P\left(E\right)+P\left(F\right)+P\left(G\right)-P\left(E\cap F\right)-P\left(F\cap G\right)-P\left(E\cap G\right)+P\left(E\cap F\cap G\right)=$$$$3\times6^{-3}-2\times6^{-4}-6^{-5}+6^{-5}=16\times6^{-4}$$

This tells us also that there are $16\times6=96$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sf X$ be a result of `1`, $\sf Y$ be a result of something else, and $\sf Z$ be a result of anything. The disjoint outcome patterns for "at least three consecutive `1` among five rolls" are: $$\sf XXXZZ~, YXXXZ~,ZYXXX$$ So the probability is $$\dfrac{1^3\cdotp6^2+5\cdotp1^3\cdotp6+6\cdotp5\cdotp1^3}{6^5}=\dfrac{1}{81}$$